# Prompt for generating two characters in the same scene

Tags: leonardo.ai

There's a core issue with the AI tools that i'm having trouble with.
I generated my characters as I wanted, but then trying to combine them in a single image is very hard.

Character one:
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/6d3d2e40-0b1e-4de9-9389-68092e3e285c/3D_Animation_Style_A_little_girl_named_Shira_multiple_poses_an_0.jpg

Character two:
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/185b039c-a52d-444b-b0eb-61c260b0d226/3D_Animation_Style_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Ricky_with_a_0.jpg

I was able to combine the first character ( Shira ) as I wanted, in her room:
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/355edaed-a02e-4b35-b6ca-1f72de23f8b3/variations/Default_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Shira_with_a_closeup_sho_0_355edaed-a02e-4b35-b6ca-1f72de23f8b3_1.jpg

Now I want the 2nd Character - with Shira on the bed ( at the end of the bed )
Meaning; two characters that I have already generated - sitting on the same bed.

And no matter what i do i'm unable to perform this, it always generate either one of the character or resulting a very strange pictures.

I'm having trouble with also just adding a dog to Shira, just like this one which was very easy in nightcafe.studio:
https://creator.nightcafe.studio/creation/6lZ6byRB9Tg1s5lo5out
But very very hard in Leonardo.AI ... impossible to add another character.
The AI just don't understand what I want.

Example of a prompt:
https://cdn.leonardo.ai/users/534e99c8-e136-474b-86e8-dc4e5c456fca/generations/2f08d300-ebc9-4a71-900a-200dbe7a2634/3D_Animation_Style_cartoon_personality_Introduce_Ricky_Ricky_h_0.jpg

```
cartoon, personality: Introduce Ricky. Ricky has a brown long hair with brown eyes and white shirt. Introduce Shira with a close-up shot. Focus on her curious and wide-eyed expression, capturing her scenes of wonder and innocence, Shira has a red curly hair with brown eyes and white shirt, Shira is in her room, Shira is sitting on a bed hugging Ricky. close-up shot.
```

I also tried to "train" my own model, created all kinds of pictures of Shira, then just wanted to use the word in the prompt "Shira" and thought that will do it - but it gave me completely different characters ...

Any tips ?

### Edit - canvas edit try

So I tried taking the picture with the girl in the bed, and painted a mask on the other side of the bed, then placed the square there, pasted the same prompt as above, and something came out, but the character is very small compared to the other characters ... :/

[image]

Comment: Not an answer just more of the same question. Combining two distinct characters into an image is very difficult. I have not been able to find a real solution. I would like the AI image to create one distinct character and have another character not facing the camera and have not had any success doing that yet. AI image creation is awesome but if I need to still use photoshop or some other photo editing program to combine my two distinct characters into the same image is that really a great solution? Any new suggestions ????